# Reference to default text color in android (light/dark mode)

Tags: android, kotlin

In Swift, this property is available (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173131-label):

`open class var label: UIColor { get }`

When the device is in dark mode, this returns white, and if the device is in light mode, this return black.

I am wondering if there is such a property/function in android available (no jetpack compose, I am using `ConstraintLayout`). Ofcourse I can create my own method, but I am wondering if android provides us something already.